# Finding most recent values of an element in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
HOME    AWAY    COUNT_H    COUNT_A    N_H     N_A
Wild    Sharks    1          1        0.5    -0.4
Jets    Sabres    1          1        0.7     0.3
Sharks  Wild      2          2        0.2    -0.1
Jets    Stars     2          1       -0.2     0.4
Stars   Wild      1          3        0.7     0.3
Sharks  Sabres    3          2        0.5    -0.4
```

I need to create two new columns 'K_H' and 'K_A' which show what the 'N_H' and 'N_A' were when the count was one number less than what the current row indicates.

For example, my desired output is this:

```
HOME    AWAY    COUNT_H    COUNT_A    N_H     N_A    K_H     K_A
Wild    Sharks    1          1        0.5    -0.4    n/a     n/a
Jets    Sabres    1          1        0.7     0.3    n/a     n/a
Sharks  Wild      2          2        0.2    -0.1    -0.4    0.5
Jets    Stars     2          1       -0.2     0.4    0.7     n/a
Stars   Wild      2          3        0.7     0.3    0.4    -0.1
Sharks  Sabres    3          2        0.5    -0.4    0.2     0.3
```

I'm quite lost here. I've attempted to slice the dataframe whilst creating the new columns, but this isn't working. I've also made a for loop but it's unbearably slow. I can do it pretty easily in Excel using INDEX(MATCH()) functions, but I really need something for pandas.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks